# the scope of static function in c

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory, storage-class-specifier

Once I've heard that function, which are declared as static, are placed not in stack, but in heap. Now, when I'm studying this, I found that quite interesting, but it looks like not true. So is it really true? Or is there any way to do that (put function on heap on it's lifetime)?

Comment: Code is placed in neither the "stack" nor the "heap". I'm afraid you may have misunderstood something.

Comment: You are probably thinking of static locals?

Comment: I think I wrote my post incorrectly. I know that code (instructions) is placed in text segment etc. I've meant locals by saying "function is placed...".

Answer (score 3):

*Functions* are not placed on the stack or on the heap. A function (i.e., the code that implements it) is typically placed in some region of memory, often marked by the OS as read-only, that's loaded from the executable file when the program starts.

The `static` keyword on a function definition affects the visibility of its name. A `static` function's name is visible only within the translation unit that defines it. It can still be called from other translation units (source files) if you use a pointer rather than calling the function by its name.

Storage for variables defined within a function are typically allocated on the "stack" if they're not defined as `static`, or in some global memory region if the are defined as `static`. The "heap" is used only for memory allocated by `malloc` and similar functions.

Note that the C standard does not use the terms "stack" or "heap", and different C compilers might use them differently if at all. Local variables in a function are allocated in a stack-like manner, but the standard says nothing about how that "stack" is implemented (for example, it's not necessarily contiguous in memory).